# Making azuremobileclient globally accessible in Ember.js

Tags: javascript, azure, ember.js, azure-mobile-services

I am using the ember-app-kit to build an SPA and am also using azure mobile services on the backend of it to hold my data. I am currently forced into declaring:

```
var client = new WindowsAzure.MobileServiceClient(
        "xxxxxx",
        "xxxxxx"
        );
```

I have been doing this declaration in all of my models and controllers. How can make this globally relevant to my application?

Comment: Have you tried building a custom adapter to consume the Azure API? See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17938294/how-do-you-create-a-custom-adapter-for-ember-js