# Ember-data Why does it need to know which attrs will i use?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Can't Ember-data just see the JSON response it gets and understand by it which attributes are used by the server?
For example if the response for 'GET /api/user/1' is like:

```
{
    id: 1,
    first_name: 'Miki',
    last_name: 'Coco',
    age: 17
}
```

Its pretty obvious that the user model has just first_name, last_name and age.

Why would i need to configure it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the things that I can think of off the top of my head.

1. Change management (isDirty)
2. Serialization/deserialization of different types
3. You can put other properties on the model that won't necessarily be sent back to the server on save etc
4. Relationship handling

Honestly, I avoid Ember Data for simple models that I don't need CRUD for, it's overkill (unless I'm worried about client side caching etc)

Comment: Seems like it is an overkill for nosql too, are you using Ember-model? or just add your $.ajax methods?

Comment: one project we're using Ember Model, but when it comes to relationships it's overkill as well, I roll my own adapter using $.ajax... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17938294/how-do-you-create-a-custom-adapter-for-ember-js/17938593#17938593

Comment: I guess i'll roll my own too, the linked post will help me get started at it thanks :)