# EmberJS $.ajax record fetching returns undefined for model in setupController

Tags: javascript, ajax, ember.js, ember-data

Ember-Data is great, but I needed something custom to fetch a user by the `invitation_token` but also call a different controller action entirely on the backend Rails side.

Here's my route:

```
MyEmberApp.InviteRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    var self = this;
    var user;
    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: 'api/v1/users/invite?invitation_token=' + params.token,
      success: function(response) {
        user = self.store.createRecord('user', response.users[0]);
        console.log(user);
        return user;
      },
      error: function(response) {
        console.log("Something went wrong.");
      }
    });
  },
  setupController: function(controller, model) {
    controller.set('model', model);
    console.log(model);
  },
});
```

In `setupController` the `console.log(model)` is undefined - is this because I'm using an `$.ajax` call? What do you suggest I do? I can't use pure ember-data because I need to protect  and authorise users on a per rails controller basis.

Comment: This may help eviltrout.com/2013/03/23/ember-without-data.html

Comment: Or this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24408892/ember-without-ember-data/24411550#24411550, or this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17938294/how-do-you-create-a-custom-adapter-for-ember-js/17938593#17938593

Answer (score 2):

You're missing your return statement.

```
  model: function(params) {
    var self = this;
    var user;
    return $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: 'api/v1/users/invite?invitation_token=' + params.token,
      success: function(response) {
        user = self.store.createRecord('user', response.users[0]);
        console.log(user);
        return user;
      },
      error: function(response) {
        console.log("Something went wrong.");
      }
    });
  },
```