# How can I represent a model with multiple different serializations in Ember?

Tags: serialization, ember.js, ember-data

I have a `Client` model. When viewing `/clients`, I want to return a simple serialization of my clients, with just a few aggregate values (lets say `total_unbilled` and `total_owing`). When viewing `/clients/1`, I want to return a full serialization of the client, including all it's nested tasks and expenses. The back-end has already been configured to do this.

I don't want to return the full serialization of all clients when the user views `/clients`, as there can be a lot of data under potentially hundreds of clients. I'd like to load that extra information only when needed, when the user views a particular client.

What's the best way to handle this use-case, where models can be serialized in multiple ways, using Ember Data? I know it will cache the initial representation of the client, so if the user visits `/clients` first, it won't ever try to fetch the full serialization of the client if the user then visits `/clients/1`. Is there a sensible way to override this? Or would I have to have two different Ember Data models client-side (eg. `Client` and `MiniClient`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly the easiest is to use two different models, or just don't use Ember Data for the mini clients.  It sounds like they won't be used for much more than just an info.

I'd possibly just do POJOs for the mini client, and Ember Data for the full client (since caching would be most useful at that point) [Ember without Ember Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24408892/ember-without-ember-data/24411550#24411550)