# Ember-data find record by id and also additional parameters?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

In the Ember docs I found that find() has support for finding by id:

```
this.store.find('post', 1); // => GET /posts/1
```

And also by passing arbitrary parameters:

```
this.store.find('post', { name: "Peter" }); // => GET to /posts?name='Peter'
```

But in my case I must find by id, and pass an additional parameter to request all fields to be included in the response (some are omitted by default), like so:

```
this.store.find('post', 1); // => GET /posts/1?include=all
```

I tried to do it this way:

```
this.get('store').find('post', params.post_id, { include : 'all' });
```

But my params were ignored.

This seems a fairly basic use case so I must be missing something...

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Do you have a custom adapter? If so, can you paste it?

Comment: Here is a most-excellent explanation of what to do when "Oh noes, my REST API and Ember-Data hate eachother.", courtesy of @kingpin2k http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17938294/how-do-you-create-a-custom-adapter-for-ember-js

Comment: I have looked into Ember's implementation and to implement this I would have to override 3 or 4 methods in the Store, plus the ones in the adapter so given parameters are passed along to it. It's not terrible, but I'd like to avoid this kind of major overriding due to the fact Ember changes quite a bit over time and I'd have to be checking each time I upgrade for compatibility issues, and I'd also possibly miss on improvements they release. I'm thinking to make a pull-request for this, not sure if it'd be accepted but I kinda get the feeling unfortunately it would not.

Comment: Support looks to be on the way.... https://github.com/emberjs/data/pull/3976

Comment: @KeithBroughton the pull request doesn't solve the problem described by the original question (passing arbitrary parameters to a `GET /posts/:id` request)

Answer (score 3):

You may have found a workaround the problem by now, but the way to go is to use the `adapterOptions` on the `options` argument.

So, let's go:

1. Where you fetch the model (i.e. a route), setup the custom argument you want. In your case, the include. It goes like this:

   ```
   //file app/routes/post/edit.js

   import Ember from 'ember';

   export default Ember.Route.extend({
     model: function(params) {
       return this.store.findRecord('post', params.post_id, {
         adapterOptions: { include: 'all' }
       });
     }
   });
   ```
2. Read this value inside the model's adapter to customize the ajax request:

   ```
   //file app/adapters/post.js

   export default JSONAPIAdapter.extend({
     findRecord: function(store, type, id, snapshot) {
       if (Em.get(snapshot, 'include')) {
         let url = this.buildURL(type.modelName, id, snapshot, 'findRecord');
         let query = this.buildQuery(snapshot);
         return this.ajax(url, 'GET', { data: query });
       } else {
         this._super(...arguments);
       }
   });
   ```

#### UPDATE 1:

On the ember-data newer versions (>= 2.4.0) you can do it out of the box, by calling 
`store.findRecord('post', {include: 'all'});`

Comment: In your update, are you sure that works? Didn't work for me. Raises error: "Assertion Failed: `id` has to be non-empty string or number"

Comment: It works with include but if you need to pass another query does not work.

Answer (score 2):

PhStoned's code works but would cause errors if adapterOptions is blank. Here is an improved version.

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import applicationAdapter from './application';

export default applicationAdapter.extend({
  findRecord: function(store, type, id, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.adapterOptions)) {
      let url = this.buildURL(type.modelName, id, snapshot, 'findRecord');
      let query = {
        include: Ember.get(snapshot.adapterOptions, 'include')
      };
      return this.ajax(url, 'GET', { data: query });
    } else {
      return this._super(...arguments);
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use queryRecord instead of find if you want to pass additional params to backend.

```
this.store.queryRecord('post', { id: params.post_id, include: 'all' }).then(function(data) {
  // do something with `data`
});
```

Comment: unfortunately, this builds a `/posts?id=X&include=all` URL instead of `/posts/X?include=all` as OP requested, and usually RESTful APIs will only support the latter

Answer (score 1):

Rodrigo Marroquim answer didn't work for me. So I've come to the following solution 
**Ember v2.6.0**

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import applicationAdapter from './application';

export default applicationAdapter.extend({
  findRecord: function(store, type, id, snapshot) {
    if (Ember.get(snapshot.adapterOptions, 'include')) {
      let url = this.buildURL(type.modelName, id, snapshot, 'findRecord');
      let query = {
        include: Ember.get(snapshot.adapterOptions, 'include')
      };
      return this.ajax(url, 'GET', { data: query });
    } else {
      this._super(...arguments);
    }
  }
});
```

usage:

```
this.get('store').findRecord('modelName', id, {
          adapterOptions: { include: 'all' }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to try using the query function rather than the find function. This will allow you to query an unlimited number of filters.

```
var myStore = this.get('store');
myStore.query('post', { 
    _id: params.post_id,
    include : 'all'
 }).then(function(peters) {
      // Do something with `peters`
});
```

Comment: unfortunately, this builds a `/posts?id=X&include=all` URL instead of `/posts/X?include=all` as OP requested, and usually RESTful APIs will only support the latter

Answer (score 0):

May helpful to use ajax with adapter implementation here:

```
const { getOwner } = Ember;
let adapter = getOwner(this).lookup('adapter:application');
adapter.ajax(
  adapter.buildURL(`posts/${id}`), 'GET', { data: { include: 'all' } }
);

#> /posts/1?include=all
```

This ajax solution even better:

```
const { inject: { service } } = Ember;

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  ajax: service(),

  async model(params) {
    let id = params.id;

    return await this.get('ajax')
      .request(`/posts/${id}`, {
        data: { include: 'all' }
      }).then(({ post }) => {
        if (post) {
          return this.store.push(this.store.normalize('post', post));
        }
      });
  }
});
```