# Ember Data rewrite URL

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have the following setup:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
    this.route('tab', { 'path' : 'tab/:which' });
});

App.ApplicationStore = DS.Store.extend({});
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
    host: '../api'
});

App.TabAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  find: function(store, type, id) {

    alert("I doesn't get invoked");

    return this._super(store, type, id);
  }
});

App.TabRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    return this.store.find('emails', {tab: "inbox"});
  }
});
```

And when visiting the route `#/tab/inbox` i wanna rewrite the URL for the endpoint from 
`http://localhost/ba/api/emails?tab=inbox`into 
`http://localhost/ba/api/emails/inbox`. Therefore i'm overriding the `find()`-method on the TabAdapter, but when `this.store.find('emails', {tab: "inbox"});` runs, it doesn't enter my overridden method(and my test-alert doesn't get invoked).

Why does my overridden `find()`-method not get invoked?

Comment: I'm new to Ember, but is there a TabsController and Tab model classes as well?

Comment: Yes there are, but they are currently empty, and Ember automatically creates the controller for the route, if it's not specified. App.TabController = Ember.Controller.extend({});
App.Tab = DS.Model.extend({});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you're overriding the wrong `find` method.  You're finding by query, not id and should be overriding that method

```
 findQuery: function(store, type, query) {
    // Do your thing here
    return this.ajax(this.buildURL(type.typeKey), 'GET', { data: query });
 }
```

And you're using a `TabAdapter` which would be specific to models of type `tab` not of type `email(s)`.  You should be creating a `Email(s)Adapter`.  The general convention is for a model to be singular btw.

See also: [How do you create a custom adapter for ember.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17938294/how-do-you-create-a-custom-adapter-for-ember-js/17938593#17938593)

Comment: It still doesn't get invoked? Thats really strange. App.TabAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
 findQuery: function(store, type, query) {
    alert("I doesn't get invoked");
     return this.ajax(this.buildURL(type.typeKey), 'GET', { data: query });
 }
});