# How to post to create an Ember data model under a parent resource?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Let's say I have a parent model which has many children. The REST route for creating one of the children would look like this:

```
POST /parents/123/children
```

However, I can't seem to figure out how to set up an ember data model to have a parent. It wants to post to `/children` with a `parent_id` param. How can I set up Ember Data so that I can use the URL to identify the parent rather than passing a param?

Comment: Ember itself doesn't do any posting/getting, Are you referring to Ember Data?

Comment: Yes, I'm using ember data rest adapter.

Comment: You need to override ember adapter to support your custom url

Comment: Okay, how do I do that?

Comment: Honestly Ember Data is  PITA for this type of scenario, unless the new JSON API specifically supports a scenario like this, it's almost easier to avoid using Ember DATA.  If you want to fight with Ember Data and get this to work I'd look at this post to get your started, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17938294/how-do-you-create-a-custom-adapter-for-ember-js/17938593#17938593.  The complex portion of your question is the fact that `children` records may potentially need to post to multiple locations depending on the type of parent, and that makes for some fun code.